# How to convert string to template type

Tags: c++

I'm writing program in c++ and today  I faced following problem, and I wonder if someone could help or explain how to solve it.
Basically I have deal with template class and one of the method should take an input from user as a string value ,convert it to template value and return.
Here is how code looks like :

```
T HashTable<T>::insertValue()
{
    T value;
    string str;

    cout << "Insert value please" << endl;
    getline(cin,str);
    stringstream convert(str);
    convert >> value;

    return value;
}
```

it works perfectly fine until I input string- if I enter the whole sentence -after conversion the part after first space is lost.
is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: What type do you instantiate the template with?

Comment: This line `convert >> value;` is the problem. The `>>` operator stops reading input on white space

Comment: i have several instances of the class for strings,int,doubles ,floats and chars

Comment: Provide a specialization for `std::string`.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to reimplement boost::lexical_cast.

Answer (score 9):

Something like this?

```
template<typename T>
T getline_as( std::istream& s );

template<>
std::string getline_as<std::string>( std::istream& s )
{
    std::string str;
    std::getline(s,str);
    return str;
} 

template<typename T>
T getline_as( std::istream& s )
{
    std::stringstream convert(getline_as<std::string>(s));

    T value;
    convert >> value;
    return value;
}

T HashTable<T>::insertValue()
{
    cout << "Insert value please" << endl;
    return getline_as<T>(cin);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, helped me out! I don't understand why the first forward declaration is needed though...??

Comment: @JanMüller: Just because you can't introduce a specialization until the template is declared.  You don't need a declaration if the general case is defined before the specialization... but that's not possible here, because the general case calls the specific case.